# Escanear encuesta

Tags: r

Tengo varias encuestas en papel y tengo que meter el resultado en una base de datos, metiendo los datos a mano.

Para hacerlo más rápido había pensado en digitalizarlas y luego escanearlas con algún paquete ocr, por ejemplo con `Tesseract` en R, darle formato al texto y guardarlas como fichero csv. Luego exportarlo a la base de datos.

Pero cuando hay preguntas de este estilo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no sé como hacer destacar la opción marcada.

Alguna idea de como hacerlo? ya sea con R o con cualquier otro sofware.
También podría conseguir las encuestas directamente en formato word, y no en papel.

Alguna forma de pasar ese resultado en word a un fichero csv?

[Enlace a Mega con un docx de prueba](https://mega.nz/file/5bgmDBjD#z6H-X_mHgq5nWcSWeMdy1zAXz7TYRLCHXp3y8FzcXfs)

Comment: ¿Las encuestas se completan en papel o en Word?

Comment: Puedo tenerlas de las dos formas. Es una encuesta que se rellena en papel y también se envía por correo electrónico.

Comment: Si son archivos .docx (creo que es de Word 2007 en adelante) la ventaja es que el documento como tal está representado el formato xml. El archivo .docx no es más que un zipeado de una carpeta con xml dentro. Si le cambias la extensión a .zip puedes abrirlo con cualquier descompresor y ver que hay dentro. En principio el archivo que interesa sería `document.xml` . El trabajo pesado sería encontrar la etiqueta xml que corresponde a cada respuesta y alguna marca de formato que te indique que esa fue la elegida. 1/2

Comment: Podrías usar herramientas de web scraping para ese proceso, al fin y al cabo leen xml. Fácil no creo que sea, son documentos muy complejos y le estás apuntando a diferentes atributos (negrita, resaltado, etc.) . Pero creo que sería mucho más confiable que un ocr. Te deseo mucha suerte y si lo resuelves te agradecería mucho que lo publiques, es un problema frecuente y complicado. 2/2

Comment: El problema que son dos enfoques muy distintos, por un lado el clásico de reconocimiento de caracteres y el otro el interpretación del documento word tal como comenta mpaladino. Sería bueno que adjuntaras a tu pregunta ejemplos reales, uno de la opción completada en papel y otra con el documento word.

Comment: Subo un ejemplo con una sola pregunta. Si paso el fichero a zip y descomprimo, creo que la información interesante está en word > document.xml. Pero no veo la diferencia entre un numero con o sin las aspas de marcado.